# Updating elements in arraylist, is there a better way than this?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Im making a simple app with swing and i'm new when it comes to arraylists and listiterator. What i'm trying to do is a button that allows you to update information about people in an arraylist. Im supposed to do this without the use of for or for-each loops. Here's my code:

```
String searchedName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the first name of the person you want to update:");
ListIterator<Student> listIt = peopleArray.listIterator();
    while(listIt.hasNext()){
        String firstname = listIt.next().getFirstname();
            if(searchedName.equalsIgnoreCase(firstname){
                String newFirstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input new first name:");
                String newLastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new last name:");
                String newEmail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new email:");
                String newOccupation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new occupation:");
                listIt.previous().setFirstname(newFirstname);
                listIt.next().setLastname(newLastname);
                listIt.previous().setEmail(newEmail);
                listIt.next().setOccupation(newOccupation);
    }
}
```

This code works, but it looks weird. Do i have to jump back and fourth like that (listIt.next() and then listIt.previous()) or is there a better way?

//N

Comment: Why don't you get the `Student` (using `listIt.next()`)?  Then you can manipulate it to your heart's content w/o affecting the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You don't havwe to jumpt forth and back, make sure only call next() once. What about this:

```
    String searchedName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in the first name of the person you want to update:");
        ListIterator<Student> listIt = peopleArray.listIterator();
            while(listIt.hasNext()){
                Student studentToUpdate = listIt.next();
                    if(searchedName.equalsIgnoreCase(studentToUpdate.getFirstname()){
                        String newFirstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input new first name:");
                        String newLastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new last name:");
                        String newEmail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new email:");
                        String newOccupation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in new occupation:");
                        studentToUpdate.setFirstname(newFirstname);
                        studentToUpdate.next().setLastname(newLastname);
                        studentToUpdate.setEmail(newEmail);
                        studentToUpdate.setOccupation(newOccupation);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Didn't think of creating a "studentToUpdate" object for the loop, simple!

Comment: It's not a huge thing, but normally you'd use a generic `Iterator` rather than `ListIterator` in the second line so that the code works with any `Iterable` rather than requiring a list.  It doesn't need the extra power of `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

The normal idiom using the old iterator syntax would be:

```
Iterator<Student> studentIterator = peopleArray.iterator();
while(studentIterator.hasNext()){
  Student student = studentIterator.next();
  // Do stuff with student. For example:
  if(student.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstname)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```